# Why is method map in react native not rendering correctly?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm writing a simple app in react native and I want to show a grid of buttons; I'm trying to fetch the title of these buttons from a .json file.
This is the portion of code i have problems with:

```
import { View , Button, Text, Pressable} from "react-native";
import "./wordpuzzle.json";
import puzzle from "./wordpuzzle.json";

const Row = ({  }) => (
    <View style={styles.row}> </View>
  )

function Griglia(){
    
    return(
        <>
         <View style={styles.app}> 
                {puzzle.square.map(row =>(                  
                    <View > 
                                                
                        {row.map( lettera =>(
                            <>
                                {console.log(row)}
                                {console.log(lettera)} 
                            <Button onPress={()=>{console.log(lettera)}} title={lettera} color="cff3f2"> </Button> 
                            </>                         
                        ))}                     
                    </View>                     
                ))}
          </View>
        </>
    );
}
const styles = {
    app: {
    flex: 4, // the number of columns you want to devide the screen into
    marginHorizontal: "auto",
    width: 400,
      },
      row: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        borderWidth:  1,
    },
    "1col":  {
        flex:  1
      },
    
};
export default Griglia
}
```

The map method works fine (the console.log of *row* and *lettera* works), but it doesn't show anything on the page i'm calling the function *Griglia* into.

Also, this is the code of the page in question:

```
import React from "react";
import {Button, Text, View} from "react-native";
import Griglia from "../components/griglia";

function Gioco(){
    return(
        <>
        <View>
            <Griglia/>
        </View>
        </>
    );
}

export default Gioco
```

And this is the App.js:

```
import { NavigationContainer, StackRouter } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Gioco from './pages/gioco';
import Home from './pages/home';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
            <Stack.Screen name="gioco" component={Gioco} options={{title: "Ruzzle"}} />  
        </Stack.Navigator > 
    
{/*             <Form> </Form> //da mettere in un'altra pagina 
        <StatusBar style="auto" /> */}
        
    </NavigationContainer>
    </>
    );
}
```

Edit: this is what the page looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5cUT.png

Comment: Your button doesn't have any text

Comment: what text? isn't it called "title" in react native? I'm looking at the react native documentation

Comment: It should rather be `<<Button onPress={console.log(lettera)} title={lettera} color="cff3f2" />` then

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: Try removing   {console.log(row)} and {console.log(lettera)}. You shouldn't be having plain JS code in map's return. If you want them do as in @Psartek's answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{row.map(lettera => {
    console.log(row)
    console.log(lettera)
    return <Button onPress={()=>console.log(lettera)} title={lettera} color="cff3f2" />
})}
```

You also should install prettier to clean your syntax.

Comment: i've changed it, but it still doesn't works. My issue is not with console.log but with the _<Button/>_ being showed on the page _"Gioco"_

Comment: The code is correct. I would advise to debug by simplifying your code, replace button by text, and check step by step

Answer (score 0):

you have to write 'return' in map methods

like:

```html
 <>
         <View style={styles.app}> 
                {puzzle.square.map(row =>(                  
                   return (<View > 
                                                
                        {row.map( lettera =>(
                           return (<>
                                {console.log(row)}
                                {console.log(lettera)} 
                            <Button onPress={console.log(lettera)} title={lettera} color="cff3f2"> </Button> 
                            </>)                         
                        ))}                     
                    </View>)                     
                ))}
          </View>
        </>
```

Comment: I've tried it but it still doesn't work

Comment: instead of </Button> it should have self closing tag like:       <Button onPress={console.log(lettera)} title={lettera} color="cff3f2" />